# Python in Terminal, How to show long text in table format in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, terminal, tabulate

I use [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate) to show tabled data organize better.

It makes life for Terminal junkies easier.
I have pandas `dataframe` with long text in each cell. The problem is tabulate wants to print/show all the text so it does not show the table pretty.
is there a way I could show just part of the text?

PS, **Cannot** use Jupyter or VScode or others.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Maybe this https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html ?

Comment: Thanks, already used `pprint`. not functioning well with long text.